# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax at '00'.'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
date = date.Date;
        var query = $@" SELECT t.Name AS 'Department or Division',c.RegistrationNumber AS 'Vehicle Registration Number'
                           ,v.Model + ' ' + v.Variant AS 'Model/ Vehicle Description',c.ChasisNumber AS 'VIN/ Chassis Number'
                           ,c.FirstRegistrationDate AS 'First Registration Date',Od.Reading AS 'Odometer Reading'
                           ,Od.ReadingDate AS 'Odometer Reading Date',Vc.Description as 'Vehicle Category'
                            FROM clientproductvehicles c JOIN Clients t
                            ON c.TargetClientId=t.ClientId JOIN Vehicles v
                            ON c.vehicleid=v.vehicleid JOIN VehicleCategories Vc
                            ON C.VehicleCategoryId=Vc.VehicleCategoryId LEFT JOIN OdometerReadings Od
                            ON C.Clientproductvehicleid=Od.ClientProductVehicleId
                            WHERE c.ClientId={clientId}
                            AND c.ProductId={productId}
                            AND (c.LastOdometerReading BETWEEN 14000 AND 20000 or c.LastOdometerReading BETWEEN 29000 AND 35000)
                            AND  (convert(varchar(10), Od.ReadingDate,103) = convert(varchar(10), {date},103))
                            AND ( C.VehicleCategoryId = 1)
                            AND c.ClientProductVehicleId
                                    NOT IN 
                                         (SELECT I.ClientProductVehicleId 
                                        FROM Incidents i 
                                       JOIN IncidentStates iSt
                                       ON i.IncidentId = iSt.IncidentId
                                        WHERE (i.CategoryId = 4 or i.Description LIKE '%km%')
                                        AND IncidentStatusId = 1)
                                        ORDER BY 'Odometer Reading Date' DESC";
        List<ClientProductVehicle> vehicleServiceDue = _moiFleetContext.Db.SqlQuery<ClientProductVehicle>(query).ToList();
```

I am trying to get a list of all the vehicles that have an odometer reading between those ranges and that are not in `Incidents`.

I keep receiving that error and i can`t see where i went wrong since when i run the query on SQLServer i get the results i want.

Comment: Too lengthy concatenated query, Why not a stored procedure?

Comment: @un-lucky Who cares? And how does that solve the issue?

Comment: Narrow down your query line by line, until you have the minimal query necessary to reproduce the issue. This is way too much.

Comment: You need to remove { } brackets around productid,clientid and date. You need to type [productid],[clientid],[date]

Comment: Edit your question and put the content of the variable `query`

Comment: You're interpolating `{date}` into that string, but it's not being quoted so you'll get some odd expression that *if you're lucky* the system will treat as two divisions but definitely won't be treated as a date or a string. Probably better to use parameters, if your data access library supports those.

Comment: String interpolation. SQL Injection vulnerability winner, 2017.

Comment: @Jamiec Not with a `DateTime` object, but yeah, still something to fix (as suggested in my answer)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Hello, Ive changed my name to `"",103); DELETE TABLE Users`. ie, you're assuming `date` doesnt come directly from user input.

Comment: @Jamiec `date = date.Date;` takes the `Date` property from the `DateTime` struct. But you are true in stating SQL injection must be taken serious.

Comment: @PatrickHofman sure - I missed that. Lets stop agreeing now :D

Answer (score 4):

The error is most likely in this part: `convert(varchar(10), {date},103))`

You are putting in a .NET `DateTime` object here using string interpolation. The problem is: you have to pass it in as a text (so with proper quotes) and use the correct date/time format for the database (and not your local machine).

This problem can be solved much easier by using parameters instead. In your query, use `@date` instead of `{date}` and pass in the parameter in your EF query call.

Answer (score -1):

You may have multiple problems in the query.  One problem is:

```
ORDER BY 'Odometer Reading Date'
```

SQL Server does not allow you to order by a constant.  Yes, this is a constant, not a reference to a column.

You should only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Use square braces to escape column names:

```
ORDER BY [Odometer Reading Date]
```

(You should do this in the `SELECT` as well.)

Or, better yet, give names that do not need to be escaped:

```
ORDER BY Odometer_Reading_Date
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the error given.

Comment: Another error is this `convert(varchar(10), {date},103))` the date is not quoted so it would break the SQL.

Comment: {date} is a parameter i am passing, same as {clientId} and {productId}

Comment: I fixed the error by converting to only date, seems like date = date.Date; was not getting the date only from DateTime object, so i used ToShortDateString() to get only the date